# CoreGraphics Gradient not shown on iOS4

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I have the following code that works fine on iOS5.

```
 //// Abstracted Graphic Attributes
NSString* textContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[myAnnotation.annotations count]];

//// General Declarations
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

//// Gradient Declarations
NSArray* gradient3Colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                            (id)[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor, 
                            (id)[UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor, nil];
CGFloat gradient3Locations[] = {0, 1};
CGGradientRef gradient3 = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)gradient3Colors, gradient3Locations);


//// Oval Drawing
UIBezierPath* ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect: CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, 34, 34)];
CGContextSaveGState(context);
[ovalPath addClip];
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient3,
                            CGPointMake(17.5, 17.5), 10,
                            CGPointMake(17.5, 17.5), 30,
                            kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation | kCGGradientDrawsAfterEndLocation);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
ovalPath.lineWidth = 0.5;
[ovalPath stroke];


//// Text Drawing
CGRect textFrame = CGRectMake(0, 7.0, 35, 20);
[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
[textContent drawInRect: textFrame withFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size: [UIFont systemFontSize]] lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];

//// Cleanup
CGGradientRelease(gradient3);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

This draws a circle with a grey gradient, in the middle is a number.  On iOS5 this shows correctly.  On iOS4 it does not error or alert me to using wrong API's and everything but the grey gradient is drawn!  Any ideas at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so, iOS4 for some reason didn't like the colours defined.

Using th following fixes it.

```
UIColor* myLightGrey = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.66 green: 0.66 blue: 0.66 alpha: 1];
UIColor* myDarkGrey = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.33 green: 0.33 blue: 0.33 alpha: 1];

//// Gradient Declarations
NSArray* gradient3Colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                            (id)myLightGrey.CGColor, 
                            (id)myDarkGrey.CGColor, nil];
CGFloat gradient3Locations[] = {0, 1};
```

Comment: My guess is that's an ARC-on-ios4 issue, and if you'd assigned the standard colours to variables before creating the array, it would also work.

Comment: I see this problem too ... with black and grey